# An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (<project>.deps.json) was not found: package: 'CefSharp.Common', version: '90.6.70'

Tags: c#, wpf, cefsharp

I cant start my application and I cant figure out why.
In Event Viewer I have this:

```
Description: A .NET application failed.
Application: Launcher.WPF.exe
Path: C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\31d60e42-1546-49b3-a80c-1b3e905e1cb7_0.7.7.0_x64__bd4egzefakw10\Launcher.WPF\Launcher.WPF.exe
Message: Error:
  An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (Launcher.WPF.deps.json) was not found:
    package: 'CefSharp.Common', version: '90.6.70'
    path: 'runtimes/win-x64/lib/netcoreapp3.0/CefSharp.Core.Runtime.dll'
```

Comment: If you are using .Net Core 3.1 or .Net 5 then you should use the https://www.nuget.org/packages/CefSharp.Wpf.NETCore/90.6.70 package and follow the instructions at https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/3284#issuecomment-772132523 if you are still having problems after setting the RuntimeIdentifier the you'll need to provide details on how exactly you packaged your application.

Comment: @amaitland thanks, yes it is working now when I switch to right package. I don't know why it works until now, because I had that wrong package installed from the beginning. But it doesn't matter, it works now, thank you again.